# Nested Expandable List View Exception:The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

So I have a Nested Expandable List View. I use a custom Expadable List View to implement the Second Level Expandable List View. The GroupView of the First Level is being implementing in the first adapter and the Second GroupView and its Children is being implementing in the Second adapter. Here is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private static ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
private ParentLevel mAdapter;
private ArrayList<Items> firstLevel;
private ArrayList<Items> SecondLevel;
private Map<Items, List<Items>> mapList;
private String[] NavigationDrawItemsFirstLevel;
private String[] NavigationDrawItemsSecondLevel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Closed");// changing the title of the action bar with the name of the item
    //navigation Drawer
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    //Expandable List View
    mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.list_slideMenu);
    groupList();
    ChildList();
    /**
     * changing the groupIndicator from left to right
     */
    mExpandableListView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            mExpandableListView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            //getting the width of the Expandable List view
            int width = mExpandableListView.getWidth();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                mExpandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - getDipsFromPixel(35), width
                        - getDipsFromPixel(5));
            } else {
                mExpandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - getDipsFromPixel(35), width
                        - getDipsFromPixel(5));
            }
        }
    });

    groupList();
    ChildList();
/*
    for (Map.Entry<Items, List<Items>> entry : mapList.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("bill","Key = " + entry.getKey().getTitle() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
    }*/
    // A new adapter
    mAdapter = new ParentLevel(this, mapList, firstLevel);

    //setting the adapter
    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    /**
     * toggling the sliding menu
     */
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.Opened,   R.string.Closed) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Closed");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //when openig the navigation drawer hide the keyboard
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Opened");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mActionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Convert pixel to dip , help method for changing the menu indicator from left to right
 */
public int getDipsFromPixel(float pixels) {
    // Get the screen's density scale
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}

/**
 * populate group list
 */
public void groupList() {
    NavigationDrawItemsFirstLevel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first_level);
    firstLevel = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < NavigationDrawItemsFirstLevel.length; i ++) {
        firstLevel.add(i, new Items(NavigationDrawItemsFirstLevel[i]));
    }
}
/**
 * populate Child list
 */
public void ChildList() {
    mapList = new LinkedHashMap<Items, List<Items>>();

    for(Items item : firstLevel){
        if(item.getTitle().equals("3")){
            SecondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
            String NavigationDrawItems1_3 [] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Second_level_third_item);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < NavigationDrawItems1_3.length ; i ++) {
                SecondLevel.add(i, new Items(NavigationDrawItems1_3[i]));


            }

        } else if(item.getTitle().equals("5")) {
            SecondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
            String NavigationDrawItems1_5 [] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Second_level_fifth_item);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < NavigationDrawItems1_5.length ; i ++) {
                SecondLevel.add(i, new Items(NavigationDrawItems1_5[i]));
            }
        } else {
            SecondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if(SecondLevel != null)
            mapList.put(item,SecondLevel);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mExpandableListView);
    //hiding the menu items of the action bar if the navigation drawer is open
    if(mDrawerLayout!=null && drawerOpen)
        menu.clear();

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

**The first Adapter ParentLevel with Inner Class CustomListView:**

```
public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private ArrayList<Items> firstLevel;
private Map<Items, List<Items>> mMapList;
private Activity mContext;
private List<Items> getChilds;

public ParentLevel(Activity pContext,Map<Items,List<Items>> pMapList, ArrayList<Items> firstLevel) {
    this.mContext = pContext;
    this.mMapList = pMapList;
    this.firstLevel = firstLevel;
    getChilds = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return firstLevel.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mMapList.get(firstLevel.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mMapList.get(firstLevel.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater lLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = lLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_group_item, null);
    }

    TextView lTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    lTextView.setText(firstLevel.get(groupPosition).getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getChilds.add((Items) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    final CustExpListView SecondLevelExpandableListView = new CustExpListView(mContext,groupPosition,childPosition);
    final SecondLevelAdapter mAdapter = new SecondLevelAdapter(mContext, getChilds);
    SecondLevelExpandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return SecondLevelExpandableListView;

}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
/**
 * custom Expandable List View
 */
public class CustExpListView extends ExpandableListView {
    int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;

    public CustExpListView(Context context,int i, int j ){
        super(context);
        this.intGroupPosition = i;
        this.intChildPosition = j;

    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, intChildPosition);
    }
}
}
```

**This is the second Adapter:**

```
public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private List<Items> ThirdLevel;
private Context mContext;
private List<Items> SecondLevel;
private Items key;
private Map<Items,List<Items>> map;

public SecondLevelAdapter(Context pContext,List<Items> plist) {

    this.mContext = pContext;
    this.SecondLevel = plist;
    /**
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SecondLevel.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("bill","place: " + String.valueOf(i) + " price: " + SecondLevel.get(i).getTitle());
    }
  */
    ThirdLevel = new ArrayList<>();

    map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Items item : SecondLevel){
        if(item.getTitle().equals("3.2")){
            ThirdLevel = new ArrayList<>();
            String itemsTrirdLevel [] = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Second_level_third_item);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < itemsTrirdLevel.length ; i ++) {
                ThirdLevel.add(i, new Items(itemsTrirdLevel[i]));
            }
        } else {
            ThirdLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if(ThirdLevel != null)
            map.put(item,ThirdLevel);
    }

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return SecondLevel.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return map.get(SecondLevel.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return map.get(SecondLevel.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
/**
 * second level
 */
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater lLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = lLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    TextView lTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_fl);
    lTextView.setText(SecondLevel.get(groupPosition).getTitle());

    return convertView;

}
/**
 * third level
 */
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Items item = (Items)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

    LayoutInflater lLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = lLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.second_level_child_item, null);
    }

    TextView lTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_SL);
    lTextView.setText(item.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

**This is the model:**

```
public class Items {
public Items(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Items(Boolean hasChild) {
    this.hasChild = hasChild;
}

public Items(String title, Boolean hasChild) {
    this.title = title;
    this.hasChild = hasChild;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Boolean getHasChild() {
    return hasChild;
}

public void setHasChild(Boolean hasChild) {
    this.hasChild = hasChild;
}

private String title;
private Boolean hasChild = false;
}
```

Also i have 3 layouts that displays the Items of each level. The exception that i take is this:

> Process: com.example.stonesoup.doublelevelexpandablelistview, PID: 2008
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(-1, class com.example.stonesoup.doublelevelexpandablelistview.ParentLevel$CustExpListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ExpandableListConnector)]

A little i have understand from my search is that the adapter must be notified about the changes of the dataset. The problem is that i don't know where the changes is being made. Also, despite the fact that i used everywhere notifyDataSetChanged i could not resolve the problem. Also i use runOnUiThread where ever i thought that changes is being made.

Thank you for your time !!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually , i found solution , the problem was on onMeasure of the CustExpListView. Also, the way of passing from the first adapter to the second adapter a list was wrong, because the list was expanding all the time if the user was pressing the child , so i altered the constructor of the second adapter to has as an argument an Item , and this Item was being added to a new list inside the constructor of the second adapter .

**New code on  :** https://github.com/basilisfou/STONESOUP/tree/master/DoubleLevelExpandableListView